# Excessive Assembly Code Generated by MSVC for Simple C++ Function

Tags: c++, assembly, visual-c++, masm, cl

I have a small C++ program as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int add(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    int b = 20;

    std::cout << "add(a + b) = " << add(a, b) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling this code on Windows 10 using the MSVC compiler with the following command:

```bash
cl /c /FA main.cpp
```

I've noticed that the generated assembly code is surprisingly large, consisting of thousands of lines. However, when I use godbolt.com to inspect the assembly output, it shows only a few lines of code.

I would appreciate it if someone could help me understand why MSVC is producing such lengthy assembly code for this seemingly straightforward C++ function. Are there specific compiler flags or settings I should be aware of to reduce the verbosity of the generated assembly? Is this behavior expected, or am I missing something in my compilation process?

Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: When you don't ask for optimization a C++ compiler generally takes the path of **no** resistance and produces really crappy output.

Comment: godbolt by default filters out library code from assembly output. Click Filter button to disable them and you will [see similar output](https://godbolt.org/z/qesjf3EqT).

Comment: when I add the /MD flag the generated code drops from 15000+ lines to fewer than 750 lines.

Comment: In a debug build the Microsoft compiler also adds a lot of heap, range, and iterator debugging ode.

Comment: @user4581301 is there cl flag that filter out library code from assembly output like godbolt does.

Comment: @jamesdilaw Outside my wheelhouse, I'm afraid. I'd have to go digging through [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/compiler-options-listed-alphabetically?view=msvc-170) to answer that.

Comment: And on re-read, my initial comment is only sorta-relevant to this question. When I compare the [optimized with unoptimized code](https://godbolt.org/z/a8d8W8x69) purely with Godbolt, the sneaky stuff the optimizer may be doing is lost in the boilerplate.

Comment: Following the advice in the duplicate, we get https://godbolt.org/z/cdW8q88qW which is a bit smarter-looking on the optimized side once you can actually see what it did.

Comment: Generally not that interesting to look at asm for code that calls `iostream` functions, especially `std::endl` to flush for no reason right before exiting does that.  Just look at asm for functions that do something interesting, like `add`.  You don't need a `main` function at all; if you want to see how it inlines, write a simpler caller that just does that.  [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) and see Matt Godbolt's CppCon2017 talk “[What Has My Compiler Done for Me Lately? Unbolting the Compiler's Lid](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4)”